# Sending Multipart request with Jersey Client

Tags: java, rest, jersey, client, multipartform-data

I am trying to write a client in Java to obtain data from a RESTful web service. I have gone through several tutorials and videos but there is something I'm not understanding. Let me start off with this. I was able to write a clientin PHP using PEST to obtain a successful response. This is an example of how the request is made:

```
<?php
    require_once('vendor\educoder\pest\Pest.php');

    $sourceCredentials = array(
        "SourceName" => 'username',
        "Password" => 'password',
        "SiteID" => siteID);


    $params = array(
        "ResponseFormat" => 'JSON',
        "ResponseDetial => 'Full'");

    $request = array_merge(array("SourceCredentials"=>$sourceCredentials),$params);

    $pest = new Pest('https://api.something.com');

    $results = json_decode($pest->post('ClientService/GetClients',$request));

    $clients = $results->Clients;
```

I found somethings that were awkward, I'm not very familiar with RESTful clients. For some reason the site uses POST request instead of GET request. The credentials are passed in the Body as form-data as well as any query parameters. The tutorials i've viewed are not set up like this. I am not sure how to write this request in Java using Jersey. Can anyone give me some pointers on setting up this request using Jersey-client?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

form-data in Postman is for `multipart/form-data`. For that you'll want to use the [multipart module](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart) with the Jersey client. As far as code, you would just do something like

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
         .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
         .build();
FormDataMultiPart multiPart = new FormDataMultiPart()
        .field("SourceCredentials[SourceName]", "...")
        .field("ResponseFormat", "JSON")
        .field("...", "...");
Response response = client.target(url)
        .request()
        .header("...", "...")
        .post(Entity.entity(multiPart, multiPart.getMediaType());
```

And make sure you have the multipart dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version${jersey2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems another issue I was having was missing dependencies. Had to add dependency for jersey-hk2 and jersey-container-servlet. I kept getting injectionmanagerfactory not found.It seems to be receiving a response, but I dont see the client data, just the request and status information.

Comment: InboundJaxrsResponse{context=ClientResponse{method=POST, uri=https://api.******.com/ClientService/GetClients, status=200, reason=OK}}

Comment: You need to call `response.readEntity(Class)`. Passing in the type you want back. If you just want the String, then use `String.class`. If you want a POJO, then use that class. If you are going to use a POJO, then you need the `jersey-media-json-jackson` dependency also.

Comment: When trying to use POJO, i end up with an object where all the fields are null. I'm not sure if this is becuase i need to use annotation in the class for the POJO, or if its because the json string is actually an array. How could I get back a array list of POJOs?

Comment: I had read somewhere that with json there is no need to add annotations, only if your going to be using XML.

Comment: ok I think i got it now. I definitely needed annotations in my class, as well as setting up my class correctly. I appreciate the help.

Comment: if anyone has issues setting up POJO classes, this tool really helped me. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Sorry for the late response. If it is a list, then use `readEntity(new GenericType<List<MyPojo>>() {});`. The syntax is very important. Notice the `{}` at the end. This creates an anonymous class. This is something people overlook. This will return a `List<MyPojo>`

Comment: I appreciate the help, I got it working a while back. My next goal is figuring out how to use this project in an aws lambda function for Alexa. Having some trouble with that, but nothing some tutorials shouldn't solve. Thank you again for everything.